# Bounds on constant for Stirling approximation

Tags: approximation, factorial

[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) says that $$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n.$$ What is known about constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $$c_1\sqrt{n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n\le n!\le c_2\sqrt{n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ for all $n$? (If we only want the statement for any sufficiently large $n$, then any $c_1<\sqrt{2\pi}<c_2$ should work.)

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this [MathWorld@Wolfram site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html).

Comment: Inequality (26) in particular should help a lot.